# ReadInputDiscretesResponse error (Jamod,Android)

Tags: android, tcp, modbus

I'm using the library Jamod and I have trouble reading the record, what I want is to read only the record number 300 PLC I'm connected, but I get read error (enters the catch). Thanks for your help

```
package com.JR.scada;

import java.net.InetAddress;

import net.wimpi.modbus.Modbus;
import net.wimpi.modbus.io.ModbusTCPTransaction;
import net.wimpi.modbus.msg.ReadInputDiscretesRequest;
import net.wimpi.modbus.msg.ReadInputDiscretesResponse;
import net.wimpi.modbus.msg.ReadMultipleRegistersResponse;
import net.wimpi.modbus.net.TCPMasterConnection;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;




public class Main extends Activity{
    TextView text, depurar;
    EditText IP;
    Button boton;
    int i=0;


    TCPMasterConnection con = null;     //the TCP connection
    ModbusTCPTransaction trans = null;  //the Modbus transaction

    InetAddress addr = null;        //direccion del esclavo
    int port = Modbus.DEFAULT_PORT;//puerto por defecto 502 


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblRegistro);
        IP = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtIp);
        depurar = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtdepurar); 
        boton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnVerRegistro);


    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }   
    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        //Close the TCP connection
        con.close();
    }


    public class conectar extends AsyncTask<String,String,Integer>{
        ReadInputDiscretesRequest req = null; //the request
        ReadInputDiscretesResponse res = null; //the response

        int startReg;
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            try {
                //IP address;
                addr = InetAddress.getByName("212.170.50.238");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("MODBUS","IP error", e);

            }
         }
        protected Integer doInBackground(String... urls) {
            try {

                // Open the connection
                con = new TCPMasterConnection(addr);
                con.setPort(port);
                con.connect ();

                try {

                    startReg = 300;
                    // Prepare the request
                    req = new ReadInputDiscretesRequest (startReg, 1);

                    // Prepare the transaction
                    trans = new ModbusTCPTransaction(con);
                    trans.setRequest(req);
                    // execute the transaction
                    trans.execute();
                    // get the response
                    res = (ReadInputDiscretesResponse) trans.getResponse ();


                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.d("MODBUS", "Error in reading/writing");
                    return 1;
                }   


            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("MODBUS","connection error", e);

                return 1;
            }
            return 0;
        }
         protected void onPostExecute(Integer bytes) {
             if(con.isConnected()){

                 depurar.setText("conecta");
            }
             text.setText("Digital Inputs Status=" + res.getDiscretes ().toString () );

         }
    }

    public void onClick(View v)  {

       // int startReg;
        conectar conectamos = new conectar();
        conectamos.execute("hola");
}
```

error:

```
08-21 10:01:57.554: D/MODBUS(3322): Error in reading/writing
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing more about the modbus configuration on your slave PLC, my first suggestion is to try a different value for *startReg*, and see if the error persists. This will rule out problems with your Java.

Some test numbers that should work: 0,1,7,8

They may not all work, but at least one of them should return successfully.

If none of them return successfully, there may be a problem on the PLC configuration, or a problem with your request code.

If one of the test numbers is successful, you should post your results. If so, this means that you are attempting to access a memory location that does not exist on the PLC. If you access undefined PLC memory locations, often the PLC will abort the request (it does not just send back '0').

## Followup remarks:

If you find that your code works when using different values for `startReg`, but not for 300, the reason has to do with memory mapping on the PLC, and this can be different for each brand/model of PLC (post your PLC brand/model if available).

You say in your question **'record 300'**. When working with PLC, you usually don't refer to memory as a **record**. Are you trying to access Bit 300, Byte 300, Word 300, DoubleWord 300?

The real question you need to be asking, is `300` the actual **modbus address** you want to read, or is `300` how the **PLC address** is mapped (such as the 300th I/O slot, not necessarily the 300th WORD). It may be required to convert between octal, decimal, and hexidecimal addresses. Or, you may need to re-index an address (some PLCs like to start counting at `1`, but generally modbus starts counting at `0`).

Perhaps you meant to read BIT 300 (not record 300), which would then be `12th` **BIT** in the `18th` **WORD**, so it would look like this:

```
// 
startReg = 17;

// Prepare the request
// Your 300th bit should be the last value returned.
req = new ReadInputDiscretesRequest (startReg, 12);
```

The different values I suggested for `startReg` are meant to help you discover how your PLC Inputs are mapped into modbus addresses by your Java library. This might help with [number conversions](http://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/binary-octal-hexadecimal-numbers-d_1802.html).

Comment: I did what you told me, and I've tried with the numbers 0,1,7 and 8 and is not in catch. So here is what you say, but I've tried other programs and input and read 300 works perfectly, then do not know why this happens, I am desperate!. Thanks for everything

Comment: Just to confirm, when using my numbers (0,1,7,8), you **do not** get an error message, is that correct? If that is correct,try setting startReg to 191, 192, 299, 767, or 768.If those do not work, read my next post.

Comment: can you please help me with reading digital in/out from modbus server i'm always get error code 2 if i want to read them :(

Answer (score 0):

If you keep getting exceptions in your `catch` block, you might want to find out more about the error.

Try changing this line from your original code:

```
            try {
                //...
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("MODBUS", "Error in reading/writing");
                return 1;
            }
```

into this:

```
            try {
                //...
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("MODBUS", e.getMessage() );
                return 1;
            }
```

Hopefully the exception will tell you more about exactly why its failing. Post those results.

If you are getting a NULL message, you might try using a debugger to manually inspect your connection instance.